# Need some clarification on a c++ project on phone book using BST

Tags: c++

I was supposed to make a project on  a phonebook using BST in c++. I tried creating the insert function in the phonebook. I am not too confident in my code, can someone look into it an tell me if it is good enough.

Like I think I have got the basic right in my code, I just want to make sure that I got it right.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
class Details{
  private:
  string full_name;
  long full_number;
  Details* left_child;
  Details* right_child;
  public:
  Details(){
    left_child=NULL;
    right_child=NULL;
  }
  Details(string name , long number){
    full_name=name;
    full_number=number;
  }
  friend class PhoneBook; 
};
class PhoneBook{
  private:
  Details* root;
  public:
  PhoneBook(){
    root=NULL;
  }
  Details* insert(string name,long number,Details* node){
    if(node==NULL){
      Details* newnode=new Details(name , number);
      return node;
    }
    if(name.compare(node->full_name)<0){
      node->left_child=insert(name , number , node->left_child);
    }
    else{
      node->right_child=insert(name , number, node->right_child);
    }
    return node;
  }
  void create(string name , long number){
    this->root=insert(name , number, this->root);
  }
    
};
int main(){
  cout<<"Welcome to phonebook"<<endl;
  PhoneBook* project=new PhoneBook();
  int choice;
  long number;
  string name;
  while(true){
    cout<<"Put choice"<<endl;
    cin>>choice;
    switch(choice){
      case 1:
      cout<<"Enter name and number";
      cin>>name>>number;
      project->create(name , number);
      break;
      default:
      cout<<"Nil";
      break;
    }
    
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? Please provide a [mre]

Comment: I do not have any idea on how to use BST in it. Can you please tell me where to use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your phone book will have people's names and phone numbers right ?
To start, create a Person class that will have a name field and a number field.
Then you can use your BST to insert Person objects, comparing the Person objects by the name field.

In a phonebook, we use search operation most frequently. Hence it is suggested to use a BST, where average case for search operation is log(n) time.

Comment: So looks like we have to insert a whole class into a BST , but like in BST,  comparison on what grounds will I perform?

Comment: On the name field. You have a string representing the name, compare them. Like let’s say you have a name - “Rudra” and “Alan”, “Rudra” is the root. “Alan” will go towards the left side, since “Alan” is < “Rudra”.